# Trying to access height property in Custom UiView, running into "height is a get-only property" error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a custom `UIView` (DesignView) within a custom `TableViewCell` (TableViewCell) and I am trying to access the `height` property within the `UIView` so that I can grow it/shrink it when the `TableViewCell`expands/shrinks.

I am running into the error of

> cannot assign to property: 'height' is a get-only property

However after researching similar questions to mines none of the solutions/explanations seems to work.

The `DesignView` is within the `TableViewCell` and I am trying to accomplish my goal of making the `DesignView` "grow" when the cell expands in my main `ViewController`.

Here is my code for the custom `UIView`:

```
@IBDesignable class DesignView : UIView {



    var newValue : CGFloat = 0

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius : CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor : UIColor? = UIColor.black

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffSetWidth : Int = 0
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffSetHeight : Int = 1

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity : Float = 0.2

   override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius/2
    layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffSetWidth, height: shadowOffSetHeight)

    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

    layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath

    layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
    }

}
```

Here is the code for my custom `TableViewCell`:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {







    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var phoneNumberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }



    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Here is the code for my `ViewController` that contains the expand/shrink function I mentioned earlier:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var count : Int?
        if tableView == self.tableView {
        count = 3
        } else if tableView == self.pantryTableView {
            count = 7
        } else if tableView == self.foodTableView {
            count = 3
        }
        return count!
    }

    var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath? = nil

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath was called")
        var cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        switch selectedIndexPath {
        case nil:
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        default:
            if selectedIndexPath! == indexPath {
                selectedIndexPath == nil
            } else {
                    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
                }
            }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, _ sender: TableViewCell) -> CGFloat {
        let smallHeight : CGFloat = 70
        let expandedHeight : CGFloat = 180
        let ip = indexPath
        if selectedIndexPath != nil {
            if ip == selectedIndexPath! {
                return expandedHeight

            } else {
                return smallHeight

            }
        } else {
            return smallHeight

        }
    }
```

Here is where the error is occurring in my `TableViewCell`:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet var designView: DesignView!

    var height : CGFloat {
        get {
            designView.bounds.height
        }

        set {
            return designView.bounds.height = newValue
        }
    }
```

I'll also attach a screenshot so you can see what I'm trying to do/where the error is occurring:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where is the error coming from? There is no use of a `height` property anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @rmaddy when I try to create a ‘height ‘ variable in my DesignView or in my TableViewCell it shows an error so I completely deleted it

Comment: Without the code causing your issue there is no need to post the question since there is no longer any problematic code. Please update your question as needed.

Comment: Ok got you @rmaddy thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
// You can only **access** the height as it is a get-only property
print(view.frame.height)
// You can **access** the height and **modify** it 
view.frame.size.height = 50.0
```

You shouldn't need to increase the height if they are properly pinned to the edges of the Table view cell's content view.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `designView.bounds` returns a `CGRect` which is a struct. It doesn't have any property as `height`. Look the definition of `CGRect` below:

```
public struct CGRect {

    public var origin: CGPoint

    public var size: CGSize

    public init()

    public init(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize)
}
```

Obviously, `CGRect` does not have any accessible property as `height`. **This is the reason for which you are getting error.**. You should get `height` from `size` property. There is also a `return` missing in `get` method.  Replace lines of as below:

```
    var height : CGFloat {
        get {
            return designView.bounds.size.height
        }

        set {
            return designView.bounds.size.height = newValue
        }
    }
```

Hope, it will work!